# Can I view old questions that have been deleted/closed?

Tags: support, closed-questions, data-explorer, deleted-questions

I have a bad habit of trolling and a number of my questions have been deleted. Is there a way I can go back and look at them?

Can I use the [data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) and write a query to see them?

Comment: No, but the workaround I described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/333518/295232) may work.

Answer (score 3):

You can always view your own deleted posts if you have the URL for the post.

When you're under 10K and the post was deleted less then 60 days ago, you can visit your user profile, goto the Questions or Answer tab and click the 'recently deleted questions/answers' link at the bottom of the list.

When you're above 10K you can search for your own deleted posts by adding the search parameter: `deleted:1` to your search.

The Stack Exchange Data Explorer does have a table PostsWithDeleted. Unfortunately it is sanetized for deleted posts. [Only a few fields are kept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266431/158100):

- Id
- PostTypeId
- ParentId
- CreationDate
- DeletionDate
- Score
- Tags
- ClosedDate

If you know you were trolling on lets say the Haskell tag in February 2011 [the following query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1267492) gives you all deleted posts (Questions and Answers) in that tag that were created in that period:

```
select concat(
         'site://q/'
       , p.id
       , '| Deleted '
       , case p.posttypeid when 1 then 'Question' else 'Answer' end
       )
       , p.score
       , p.creationdate
       , p.deletiondate
from postswithdeleted p
inner join postswithdeleted q on q.id = coalesce(p.parentid, p.id)
where p.deletiondate is not null
and p.creationdate between '2011-02-01' and '2011-03-01'
and q.tags like '%<haskell>%'
```

That does require a lot of clicking to find your actual post but it is the only option you have left if none of the other options worked for you.

I leave it as an exercise for the reader to extend this query to use SEDE parameters and
such.

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Use the awesome [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the unforgettable [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).

Answer (score 2):

Deleted posts are omitted from the data dump, so they won't appear on SEDE. If you really wanted, you could pull old data dumps that were released after your question was asked but before it was deleted, and search those. Closed questions appear in the data dump, but they also appear publicly on the site; you can just see them in your profile normally

Comment: is there any easier way? it seems like people with very high rep can view them but i cant

Comment: @Let 10k users can view all deleted posts, but they can't search for them and they can't see them in a user's profile. You can see your own deleted posts (I think; it might only be answers), but since there's no links from your profile anymore it'd be difficult to find them. You could ask a mod to make a list, possibly