# How can I show a list of my removed posts?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, post-ban

I have a question ban on Stack Overflow. I read that I must improve my posts if I want to be unlocked, but I deleted 2 of my questions. How can I see the full list of my removed posts and undelete my questions? I would like to improve them.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140683/allow-banned-users-to-see-their-own-deleted-posts

Comment: The problem is that you cannot. There are feature requests here on Meta to address that problem.

Comment: This is the feature-request that needs to be implemented: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot list your own deleted post. A moderator, however, can.

Flag one of your posts for a moderator's attention, and say you wish to improve your deleted posts, so that they can be reopened.

A ♦ moderator will undelete all of your posts for you.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, it's good idea. I want to click "contact us" also.\

Comment: @Ty221: Try flagging first, it's likely to be quicker.

Comment: ok, i flagged my question. This is my messeage for moderators :

Comment: I'm banned on Stack Overflow (i can't create questions). I want to improve my questions, but i can't undelete my old posts. Please undelete my all deleted post because I want to improve it. I want to be unlocked. Yours faithfully

Comment: @Ty221: Great :) Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for help, moderator undeleted my posts !

Comment: @Ty221 - I undeleted all but one, because that one was closed as an exact duplicate of one of your closed questions and deleted by the community. It wasn't salvageable, and I didn't want to override a community decision there.

Comment: @Brad Larson thanks for your help. Can you give my any suggestions to my questions >

Comment: @Ty221 - In general, you need to provide a lot more detail in your questions explaining what you've tried and where you're having a specific problem. This question, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14204720/android-hidden-application is just asking us to describe the entire process to you, which is asking way too much of the volunteers on this site. Meet us halfway and show that you've put in some effort researching your questions.

Comment: I edited all my post. I improved issues descriptions, i added solutions, what's have I tried information, etc. Can you now unlock me ?

Comment: @Ty221: That's up to the community to decide. The post ban is automatic, it will be lifted when your posts are upvoted enough, to prove you've improved your quality. Nonetheless, I will review them and upvote on any worthy post.

Comment: @Madara Uchiha - thanks

Comment: @Ty221 edit like [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202157/android-google-play-licensing) isnt much useful your question is same as before it deleted .. please ask like a question you can read [Writing the perfect question-John skeet](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) its really helpful and nice