# Do you think banning for people not upvoting your question should be a thing?

Tags: feature-request, voting, down-votes, post-ban

I'll explain myself better...

There is a funny ban feature on Stack Overflow that bans you if your questions **aren't well received** by the community.
Now.. let's define "aren't well received":
A **non well received** question is a question that:

1. **Has downvotes**
2. **Is marked as duplicate** (or other stuff..)
3. **Has no upvotes**

I totally agree with the first 2 points... **people who can't ask deserve a downvote** as much as people that ask already answered questions, and, in these cases, **the ban is totally fair**.

**The third point though is hilarious and total BS to me!**

Most of the Stack Overflow community doesn't even consider that "upvote button".  Sometimes people who ask for questions **don't even choose a correct answer** (even if it has been given).

How do moderators think that just because no one upvoted my question then it automatically becomes a "not good question".

To me that makes no sense at all.
I've been banned for this motivation and I ensure you that my questions were all well received. You can check them if you want.
But hey...it looks like that just because nobody upvoted that they are just bad.

The only way this ban will make sense to me is if the upvote/downvote feature becomes a **"Must"**.
If upvoting can decide whether I can ask questions or not people who don't upvote/downvote deserve a ban as well!

Comment: Deleted questions does count in a question ban, maybe you just deleted the not so good ones?

Comment: Point of order: a zero voted question isn't, "well received".  It's, at best, neutral, and maybe just hasn't been seen yet.

Comment: @fbueckert I can guarantee you that most of this community doesn't upvote questions even if they're good.
If you don't trust me just take a look at the main page

Comment: And?  They don't have to.  How is that a problem?  Asking questions is a privilege, not a right.  It's worth mentioning that askers are kind of biased towards their questions; just because *they* think the question is good, doesn't mean it actually *is*.

Comment: @fbueckert ok, but why if I don't get upvotes I get banned?
Cause that's clearly what happened to me.
All neutral questions apart from one with 1 downvote (randomly given I would say)

Comment: @fbueckert I agree with the "they don't have to" but why do I deserve a ban if they don't tho XD

Comment: Read the link you're given.  The system thinks your track record isn't good enough to ask another question.  You get multiple warnings that your questions aren't being well received; it's a good idea to really make your questions count.  Writing off a downvote as random just exposes the perception that you don't need to improve your questions, the very thing the question ban is designed to target.

Comment: I just want to have a decent answer not a "look at the rules" answer.
Rules were just stupid this time... I don't deserve a ban just because no one upvoted my questions

Comment: You know how to get out of the ban; the info is all there for you.  I'd suggest reading it and taking it to heart.  We often get users telling us they shouldn't be banned, but, invariably, there are deleted posts that are contributing to the ban.  You might not be able to see them, but they're there, I'm betting.

Comment: Again, as previously mentioned, you have deleted questions with negative scores. Ask on meta.stackoverflow.com and a moderator can give you the links, so you can try to fix them and undelete them (if it's possible to improve them at all).

Comment: @Synapsis the vast majority of viewers can't up or downvote, and the vast majority of the minority that can doesn't vote at all or very little.

Comment: @mag ye that's basically what I have already written

Answer (score 15):

> Do you think banning for people not upvoting your question should be a thing?

No, that's a bad idea, and it's also a misrepresentation of how the system works.

A question with no up- or downvotes is **neutral** towards a question ban. You can ask hundreds of zero-scoring questions without facing a question ban, as long as you don't have (too) many negatively scoring questions.

Requiring people to vote is not going to work. What is the system going to do if I just close my browser after viewing a question? What if I already reached the maximum # of votes per day? What if I don't even have the reputation to vote?

Comment: What if you're not even logged in?  Can't ban someone who the system doesn't even know who it is!

Comment: then you obviously don't have enough reputation to vote :)

Comment: Just highlighting the infeasibility of trying to implement such a feature. :)

Comment: So please explain me why with all "neutral" questions and 1 downvoted questions (that probably someone randomly gave) I deserve a ban.
Give me at least 1 good motivation.

Comment: @Synapsis Deleted questions. You are certain to have some of those with negative scores. Ask a moderator on SO to give you the links.

Comment: @Synapsis Have you checked your deleted questions? Including the ones which are more than 60 days old - you can find them with [this trick](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/333518/295232).

Comment: I have deleted one question so far (checked the deleted post)... does that result in a ban? -.-