# How do I access my deleted posts?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, privileges

I recently deleted a post after discovering the information in it was irrelevant to others, but I now need to access it as there is relevant information about an ongoing issue I am having with my operating system.

I read *[here](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)* that the post's author has access to the deleted posts:

> **What happens when a post is deleted?**
>
> Once a post has been deleted, it will disappear for all users except
>   the post's author, developers, moderators, and users with this "access
>   to moderator tools" privilege. However, deleted posts can be undeleted
>   by casting undelete votes. Once a post has 3 undelete votes (more for
>   highly-active questions), it will no longer be deleted.

But when trying to look through my own questions I don't see them.

Is there a way for me to access my deleted posts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) In particular the section headed **Can I still see my post even after it's deleted?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645/282094) and  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343215/282094

Comment: @Rob yes sort of. It says I have no deleted questions within the last 60 days, but im pretty sure I do.

Comment: If they have been voted on, you might be able to find them with my workaround described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/333518/295232).

Comment: KalamalkaKid, another hack (if it's within not too many days) is to: 1.  Go to any question and then click on your URL bar (of your browser) and copy the URL, 2: Go to your browser's History and paste the copied link back into the URL bar, 3: Click on the tail of the URL and delete characters until you are down to "questions" - like this: `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/`, 4: Now scroll through your History and try to find the URL, 5: **IF** you have access (10K, mod, CM, owner) and it's not nuked you *should* be able to click on the History's URL and see the post, or get the Panda.