# How can I view all my automatically deleted questions

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, community-user, robots

Scenario 1:

1. I ask a Stack Overflow question
2. Link it to a GitHub issue
3. The GitHub project maintainer is unresponsive for one year
4. The question does not get much attention
5. After one year the question gets deleted automatically by the Community bot
6. After one year and half the maintainer responds cannot find the question.

Scenario 2:

1. I ask a Stack Overflow question
2. The question does not get much attention
3. After one year the question gets deleted automatically by the Community bot
4. After one year and half the there is a solution to the question.
5. I cannot find my question anymore, to self-answer it.

---

Both of these scenarios happened to me, and actually today I found that the Community
bot deletes old questions with no activity.

So, the obvious question is, what's the easiest way for me to view/list all the deleted questions, deleted by the Community bot?

I remember a couple of months ago I was searching a particular question I was really sure I asked on Stack Overflow at some point, but just couldn't find it. I assume now that is just deleted.

I just want to see all my current questions deleted by the Community bot. How can I do that?

This is applicable to any site on the network, but I took Stack Overflow as example because that's where I am mostly active.

---

Example: I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59585144/1420197), linked it to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/jarek-foksa/xel/issues/97) which was reopened recently, but the question was deleted at some point.

Comment: You can see all your deleted questions (because you have 10k rep on Stack Overflow, otherwise you could use [my workaround](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/333518/295232) or wait until [later this year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374184/295232)). I bet most of them will have been Roomba'd - user/moderator deletion is reserved for very bad questions.

Comment: @Glorfindel I am a bit confused why this question was closed as duplicated, because all these linked questions do not really have a solution to my case. Would that mean in about one month I should have access to see all my deleted posts?

Comment: You already have it now: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+is%3Aq+deleted%3A1

Comment: @IonicăBizău other than on stack overflow (where Glorfindel's comment works), you can't.

Comment: @Glorfindel Ah, that's so handy! 74 results -- quite a few! Thanks for helping me.